# Организация загрузки данных в post контроллере из разных источников

Tags: java, json, spring, post, rest

Нужна помощь в таком вопросе.

Возморжно ли расширить спектр способов передачи в post данных.
Поясню.
Сейчас я могу передать данные, ну к примеру .jpg по url ссылке.

интерсено можно ли еще добавить поддержку multiuploads и через json.

т.е. чтобы 3 способами можно было передавать данные не создавая при этом новых методов post в контроллере.